# Stein and Shakarchi, prove $L^1$ convergence of the averaging sequence over dyadic cubes

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I saw a statement in Stein's Harmonic Analysis (Page 129). A similar exercise can also be found in Stein-Shakarchi's Functional Analysis (Page 93, exercise 18), but I can't prove it.

> Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. For each $k$ define $f_k(x)$ as
> $$ f_k(x)=2^k \int_{l\cdot2^{-k}}^{(l+1)\cdot2^{-k}} f(u) du,  \quad  x\in (l\cdot2^{-k}, (l+1)\cdot2^{-k})  $$
> (basically the sequence $f_k$ is obtained by averaging $f$ over each dyadic cube of *k*th generation.)
> Show that $f_k \rightarrow f$ in $L^1 $ norm, as $  k \rightarrow \infty$ .

Comment: What have you tried ? where are you stuck ? moreover, $f_k$ is not clear... where does $\ell$ and $k$ belong ? $\mathbb Z$ ?

Comment: Maybe substitution?

Comment: @Surb Yes  $\mathbb Z$. I think Dominated Convergence theorem should be used here, however I can figure out an integrable function to bound the sequence $f_k$